# List won't show up correctly when integrated with PHP

Tags: php, html

I made a database that has a points system, and to convert this to ranks I planned on showing the data from the database from highest to lowest, then using a list to display it with numbers. However, when displaying it as a list it just shows up as:
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.

(going on until it reaches 10)

Which is not how it should act, I have tried changing the stuff up around the code and the results have only worsened. Can anyone help?

```
    <?php 
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gg");       
 $mw2ranks = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM qsmw2 ORDER BY points DESC") ;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mw2ranks))
{
echo "<td><ol><li style='list-style-type:decimal;'> ".$row['points']."</li></ol></td>   <td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";

}
?>
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, `<td>` tag is causing the trouble here. Try the same code without `<td>`'s

Comment: Use `<ol></ol>` around your `<li></li>` tags to have a ordered lists. And remove your `<td>` tags.

Comment: why there is `</tr>` in your code without opening it at the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments remove your

```
<td>
```

tags or do a table instead of an ordered list and better use ' instead of " for surrounding html tags with attributes in it and use the " for the attribute values, because then you get valid html and no problems in php.
Correct code for list would be:

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gg");        
$mw2ranks = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM qsmw2 ORDER BY points DESC") ;

echo "<ol>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mw2ranks))
{
  echo '<li style="list-style-type:decimal;"> '.$row['points'].'</li>';
}
?>
</ol>
```

For a table you could use the following:

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gg");        
$mw2ranks = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM qsmw2 ORDER BY points DESC") ;
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mw2ranks))
    {
       echo "<td> ".$row['points']."</td>
    }
    ?>
  </tr>
</table
```

Comment: The only problem is, no matter how much I change my code I can't get the table and the ordered list to appear... I don't think it's even possible...

Comment: @Achilles: Maybe the problem could be that there is no content in your query. Please do 
    
    `var_dump($mw2ranks);`  
and tell me what you get displayed

Comment: Well, that's not the problem. Your first code actually does it perfectly, and lists the numbers just as done. The problem is, I can't manage to put the table on top of all of that. It just doesn't seem like they combine. But it's awesome that it works (slightly), thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sorry I'm no native english speaker, maybe that's the problem, but I don't get it. Do you want to show the list inside the table or do you wan't the table displayed above or below the list?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is broken. You can't include the `<td>` elements inside your `<ol>`. You need to create a structure like this:

```
<td>
  <ol>
    <li> Some stuff </li>
    <li> Some stuff </li>
    <li> Some stuff </li>
    <li> Some stuff </li>
  </ol>
</td>
```

Grouping your `<li>` elements like this will allow the numbering to work, but obviously it will mess up your table layout. Your alternative is to generate the numbering in your PHP script and not use the ordered list structure at all.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <?php
    $i=1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mw2ranks))
    {
       echo "<td> ".$i."</td>";
       echo "<td> ".$row['points']."</td>";
       $i++;

    }
    ?>
  </tr>
```